# Make a column hidden by a function in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to hide a column by using a function. More clearly, what I am trying to implement is, for a particular type of data bundle, which is arranged as column1, column2, column3, etc, a number is obtained from another specific cell and the columns upto that much of order are visible. ie, if I input 3 in the cell, Columns upto column3 should be visible. Can someone suggest any function or idea to implement it? Please...

Comment: No functions cannot alter any properties of cells

Answer (score 1):

This method uses the value typed in cell **A1**.  If you enter **2** only the first two columns will be visible.  Typing **3** will make three columns visible, etc.

Enter the following event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim A1 As Range, rINT As Range
    Dim N As Long

    Set A1 = Range("A1")
    Set rINT = Intersect(A1, Target)
    If rINT Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    N = A1.Value
    Columns.Hidden = False
    Range(Cells(1, N + 1), Cells(1, Columns.Count)).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

If you enter a **0**, all columns will be hidden and you will have to unhide them manually.